# Test a component with Link outside of BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I need to test a `SavedVariants` component that has `Link` in it, but the problem is that only the wrapper component defines `BrowserRouter`:

```
const RoutedSavedVariants = ({ match }) =>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${match.url}/variant/:variantGuid`} component={SavedVariants} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}/family/:familyGuid/:tagArray?`} component={SavedVariants} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}/analysis_group/:analysisGroupGuid?`} component={SavedVariants} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}/:tagArray/gene/:gene`} component={SavedVariants} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}/:tagArray?`} component={SavedVariants} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

How could I `mount` `SavedVariants`? Or how could I `mount` the `RoutedSavedVariants` but then test only `SavedVariants` (how to get it, fully rendered, from the `RoutedSavedVariants`)?

Comment: You can just wrap  `SavedVariants` in a `BrowserRouter` in your tests

Comment: That works! Thank you! If you post it I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `SavedVariants` component in a `BrowserRouter` when you write your tests.